# selecting all siblings except first

Tags: css, css-selectors

**Is there a CSS selector that selects the compliment of `.a + .b` with respect to `.a ~ .b`?**

In less mathy terms, I want to select all sibling elements that succeed an element, *excluding* its first sibling successor.

For example, in all `dl` lists, I have all `dd` elements colored a certain color. But in *inline* `dl` lists, I want to keep the first `dd` following a `dt` the same color, but all subsequent `dd`s will be changed to another color. Below is my code, which is clearly not [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Is there a way to do it without re-defining the color again?

```
/* dl lists contain dd terms all colored light aqua */
dl > dd {
    background-color: #c0ffee;
}
/* inline dl lists have dd terms displayed inline and colored yellow-green */
dl.inline > dd {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #bada33;
}
/* however, in an inline dl list, the first dd succeeding a dt is colored normally */
dl.inline > dt + dd {
    background-color: #c0ffee;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could assign the green style to ALL dds and reset this for the first-child of them.
Please check out the __"first-child" selector__ discription at
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo

Comment: According your wish to DRY code, you can enumerate multiple selectors which will be styled the same way. Just list them comma separated like

`dl > dd,`  
`dl.inline > dt + dd {`  
`background-color: #c0ffee;`  
`}`

Comment: @dsuess `dd:first-child` only selects the `dd` if it is the first child  of the parent. If the element I want is not the first child, it won't select it. A very common mistake a lot of people make is to think that `dd:first-child` will select the first `dd` child. It's easy to get confused by that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, You Can Select the Complement

In your simplified example, it would be this: `.a + .b ~ .b`. You "skip" the first `.b` by using it as the launching point for the general sibling selector.

If I understand your `dd` requirements, then it would be this:

```
/* dl lists contain dd terms all colored light aqua */
dl > dd {
    background-color: #c0ffee;
}
/* inline dl lists have dd terms displayed inline  */
dl.inline > dd {
    display: inline;
}
/* however, in an inline dl list, the first dd succeeding a dt is left 
   to be colored normally and all after it are colored yellow-green */
dl.inline > dt + dd ~ dd {
    background-color: #bada33;
}
```

But [that requires each `dt` be in its own `dl`](http://jsfiddle.net/dQKFa/1/), otherwise [you have issues](http://jsfiddle.net/dQKFa/). The general sibling selector is not going to help you if they are all under one list, because the `dl.inline > dt + dd ~ dd` is more specific than any following `dl > dd`.

### So in Your Case

[The solution is to keep from repeating code and having specificity not override under a single list is this](http://jsfiddle.net/dQKFa/2/):

```
/* dl lists contain dd terms all colored light aqua */
dl > dd,
dl.inline > dt + dd {
    background-color: #c0ffee;
}
/* inline dl lists have dd terms displayed inline  */
dl.inline > dd {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #bada33;
}
```